# Electron Builder: "Error occurred in the main process - Callback is not a function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron, electron-builder

I have built an Electron application which works properly when running from command-line using:
`npm start`

I want to deploy the application as user-friendly installers for Mac/Windows/Linux. To achieve this I am using [Electron-Builder](https://www.electron.build) for packing and building my source files. The command I use to execute the build process is: `npx electron-builder`.

When I try to run my packaged and built application, I immediately receive an error message stating:

*A Javascript error occurred in the main process 

Uncaught Exception: 

TypeError: Callback is not a function 

at ELECTRON_ASAR.js:600:9 
 at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
 at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)* 
[screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ip4a6.png)

After clicking OK on the pop-up, the application runs as expected.

I also receive this message if I use the `npm start` command **after** building with `npx electron-builder`.

I have tested on both Mac and Linux and I receive the same message. I have even tested with an empty electron project (no custom code or dependencies) and I still receive this message. Therefore I assume that it is a problem with Electron-Builder.

Any ideas as to how I can stop this error message from popping up at the start of runtime? 
Thanks.

Comment: the error occur mostly when there is problem in your code.. so make sure the builder your using should work with your electron version.. and try to use update version of electron.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an older version of Electron... Updating to the most recent stable release (currently 10.1.5) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can carry out the following suggestions

1. Delete the app data folders in %AppData% and %LocalAppData%
2. Re-register the javascript dll file
3. Reinstall skype, discord, etc, app that is having problems.

if you want a detailed breakdown on the to carry out this processes, kindly go to -->https://www.thewindowsclub.com/javascript-error-occurred-in-the-main-process